# how to add two matrices with production rules

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have two matrices, say one with 2 x 3 dimensions and the other one with 3 x 2.

```
a = [[1, 0, 1],   
     [1, 0, 1]]

b = [[1, 0],   
     [1, 0],
     [1, 0]]
```

I would like to return a 2x2 matrix c that's a sum of element-wise logical or operation between a and b.

So the result would be

```
c = [[3,2]
     [3,2]]
```

Are there any packages out there to do these operations efficiently? With very large matrices with hundreds of thousands of dimensions, looping through the elements/vectors is really slow.

This is relatively easy to return a 2x2 matrix d that is a result of addition of element-wise logical `and` operation between a and b.

`d = np.dot(a,b)` would accomplish this.  I'm wondering if there are any packages that are counterparts of np.dot with `logic or` instead.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for here, but I think you should check out numpy `ufunc`s.

Comment: Thanks! I will check it out!

Comment: How are you defining elementwise operations between arrays with incompatible shapes like these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is an object oriented approach acceptable for you ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy


class PseudoBinary(object):
    def __init__(self,i):
        self.i = i

    def __mul__(self,rhs):
        return PseudoBinary(self.i or rhs.i)

    __rmul__ = __mul__
    __imul__ = __mul__

    def __add__(self,rhs):
        return PseudoBinary(self.i + rhs.i)

    __radd__ = __add__
    __iadd__ = __add__

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.i)

    __repr__ = __str__



a = [[PseudoBinary(1), PseudoBinary(0), PseudoBinary(1)],
     [PseudoBinary(1), PseudoBinary(0), PseudoBinary(1)]]

b = [[PseudoBinary(1), PseudoBinary(0)],
     [PseudoBinary(1), PseudoBinary(0)],
     [PseudoBinary(1), PseudoBinary(0)]]

c = numpy.dot(a,b)
print(c)
```

Prints

```
[[3 2]
 [3 2]]
```

---

I have spent some time with measuring, understanding the performance of this approach. **Long story short**: this `numpy.dot` with custom objects is several orders of magnitude slower than regular matrix multiplication of integers.

I am not 100% sure of the root cause of this difference. I have asked a specific [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46018000/5771861) about the reasons of slowness.

The performance graph is like the following: 
[image]

In this plot red curve (base) is the base measurement of numpy.dot(..,..) call with integer matrixes.  Blue curve (setOr) is the approach suggested in @vortex's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45692908/5771861). The green curve is numpy.dot() performance using matrixes of custom objects. As you can see the numpy.dot with custom objects is very very slow. I got these numbers in a MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2014), 1.7 GHz Intel Core i7, 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

The code that executes the performance measurement and prints the plot is this: (Tested in python 2.7.10)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# A possible answer and performance analysis for a stackoverflow
# question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/45682641/5771861

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy
import time
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.ticker as tick
import random
import datetime
import timeit

class PseudoBinary(object):
    def __init__(self,i):
        self.i = i

    def __mul__(self,rhs):
        return PseudoBinary(self.i or rhs.i)

    __rmul__ = __mul__
    __imul__ = __mul__

    def __add__(self,rhs):
    return PseudoBinary(self.i + rhs.i)

    __radd__ = __add__
    __iadd__ = __add__

    def __str__(self):
        return "P"+str(self.i)

    __repr__ = __str__

class TestCase(object):
    def __init__(self,n):
        self.n = n

        # Only use square matrixes
        rows = self.n
        cols = self.n

    self.base = numpy.array([[random.getrandbits(1) for x in range(cols)] \
        for y in range(rows)])
    self.pseudo = numpy.array(
        [[PseudoBinary(v) for v in row] for row in self.base])

    @staticmethod
    def printMatrix(m):
        for row in m:
            for v in row:
                print(v,end=" ")
            print("")

    def print(self):
        print("base")
        TestCase.printMatrix(self.base)
        print("pseudo")
        TestCase.printMatrix(self.pseudo)

class TestRes(object):

   def __init__(self):
      self.res = []

   def append(self,v):
      self.res.append(v)

   def mean(self):
      return sum(self.res)/float(len(self.res))

def runWithTime(f,count,msg):
    start = time.time()
    for i in xrange(count):
       f()
    end = time.time()
    elapsed = end-start
    print(msg,"took",str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=end-start)),"seconds")
    return elapsed

def measureAndPrint(execCount):
   random.seed(1)

   print("Start to initialize test data")
   start = time.time()
   sizes = [1, 4, 8, 16, 32]
   testCases = [TestCase(n) for n in sizes]
   end = time.time()
   print("Test data initialization complete in ",
      str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=end-start)))

   measCount = 4

   baseResults = {}
   pseudoResults = {}
   setOrResults = {}

   for tc in testCases:
       print("Test case for",tc.n)

       def base():
       rv = numpy.dot(tc.base,tc.base)
       return rv

       res = TestRes()
       for i in xrange(measCount):
      t = runWithTime(base,execCount,"base")
      res.append(t)
       baseResults[tc.n] = res

       def pseudo():
      rv = numpy.dot(tc.pseudo,tc.pseudo)
      return rv

       res = TestRes()
       for i in xrange(measCount):
      t = runWithTime(pseudo,execCount,"pseudo")
      res.append(t)
       pseudoResults[tc.n] = res

       ones = numpy.ones(tc.n)
       dotInput = ones-tc.base
       def setOr():
      rv = ones*tc.n-numpy.dot(dotInput,dotInput)
      return rv

       res = TestRes()
       for i in xrange(measCount):
      t = runWithTime(setOr,execCount,"setOr")
      res.append(t)
       setOrResults[tc.n] = res

   return baseResults,pseudoResults,setOrResults

def isClose(a, b, rel_tol=1e-09, abs_tol=0.0):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/33024979/5771861
    return abs(a-b) <= max(rel_tol * max(abs(a), abs(b)), abs_tol)

def formatSeconds(s):
    # A concise printer for a time duration in millisecond accuracy.
    # For example 3 d 12 h 4 m 5 s 234 mi
    def maybeStr(fmt,x):
        # If x is non-zero return the formatted string with x
        if isClose(x,0):
            return ""
        else:
            return fmt.format(x)

    seconds, fraction = divmod(s, 1)
    days, seconds = divmod(seconds, 86400)
    hours, seconds = divmod(seconds, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
    milli = int(fraction * 1000)

    rv = maybeStr("{} d ",days) \
       + maybeStr("{} h ",hours) \
       + maybeStr("{} m ",minutes) \
       + maybeStr("{} s ",seconds) \
       + maybeStr("{} milliS ",milli) \

    if rv=="":
        return "0"
    else:
        return rv

def plotResults(results,color,label):
   # Get the key and values in the same order.
   res = sorted(results.items())
   xx = [x for (x,y) in res]
   yy = [y.mean() for (x,y) in res]
   plt.semilogy(xx,yy,color,label=label)
   plt.scatter(xx,yy,c=color)

   # Add an annotation to each measurement data point.
   for x,y in res:
      yValue = y.mean()
      plt.annotate(str(formatSeconds(yValue)),(x,yValue))

multiplicationCount = 1000
baseResults,pseudoResults,setOrResults = measureAndPrint(multiplicationCount)

plotResults(baseResults,"r","base")
plotResults(pseudoResults,"g","pseudo")
plotResults(setOrResults,"b","setOr")
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.title("numpy.dot() performance measurements")
plt.ylabel("Mean seconds taken by {} multiplications".format(multiplicationCount))
plt.xlabel("Dimension of square matrix")

def yFmt(val,pos):
   return formatSeconds(val)

axes = plt.gca()
yaxis = axes.get_yaxis()
yaxis.set_major_formatter(tick.FuncFormatter(yFmt))

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how fast this code compared with np.dot?

Comment: I plan to spend time about performance considerations of this too. FYI @vortex

Comment: Could you let me know how it goes? Thanks!

Comment: @vortex I have added my results of the performance measurement. FYI.

Answer (score 0):

I did figure out an alternative solution, which is just applying the set theory and using np.dot.

```
ones = np.ones((2,3))
c = np.ones((2,2))*3 - np.dot((ones-a),(ones-b))
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation why 3-dot(1-a,1-b) results in your desired outcome?

Comment: I see, for the singleton case that becomes a+b-ab, which is essentially OR. It extends to matrixes with dot product.

Comment: As long as `a` and `b` are arrays, you can just use `1` instead of that `ones` array.