# Reasons of slowness in numpy.dot() function and how to mitigate them if custom classes are used?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix

I am profiling a numpy dot product call.

```
numpy.dot(pseudo,pseudo)
```

`pseudo` is a numpy array of custom objects. Defined as:

```
pseudo = numpy.array(
         [[PseudoBinary(1), PseudoBinary(0), PseudoBinary(1)],
          [PseudoBinary(1), PseudoBinary(0), PseudoBinary(0)],
          [PseudoBinary(1), PseudoBinary(0), PseudoBinary(1)]])
```

`PseudoBinary` is a class that has a custom multiply function. It ORs instead of multiplying. See below for the complete code of PseudoBinary definition.

Type:

```
(Pdb) pseudo.dtype
dtype('O')
```

According to my profiling, the pseudo dot product is about 500 times slower than a dot product using matrixes with integer values. Pointer to the profiling code is given below.

I am interested in the reasons of the slowness and if there are ways to mitigate them.

Some of the reasons of the slowness may be:

- The memory layout of pseudo would not use contiguous memory. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29877845/5771861), numpy uses pointers with object types. During matrix multiplication, bunch of pointer dereferences may occur instead of directly reading from contiguous memory.
- Numpy multiplication may not use the optimized internal compiled implementations. (BLAS, ATLAS etc.) According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19839985/5771861), various conditions should hold for falling back to the optimized implementation. Using custom objects may break those.

Are there other factors in play? Any recommendations for improvement?

The starting point of all this was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45682641/5771861) question. There, the OP is looking for a “custom dot product”. An operation that visits the elements of two matrices similar to the dot product operation, but does something else than multiplying the corresponding elements of columns and rows.  In an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45686991/5771861), I recommended a custom object that  overwrites the `__mul__` function. But the numpy.dot performance is very slow with that approach. The code that does the performance measurement can be seen in that answer too.

---

Code showing the PseudoBinary class and dot product execution.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


 from __future__ import absolute_import
 from __future__ import print_function
 import numpy

 class PseudoBinary(object):
     def __init__(self,i):
         self.i = i

     def __mul__(self,rhs):
         return PseudoBinary(self.i or rhs.i)

     __rmul__ = __mul__
     __imul__ = __mul__

     def __add__(self,rhs):
         return PseudoBinary(self.i + rhs.i)

     __radd__ = __add__
     __iadd__ = __add__

     def __str__(self):
         return "P"+str(self.i)

     __repr__ = __str__

 base = numpy.array(
       [[1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1]])

 pseudo = numpy.array(
          [[PseudoBinary(1), PseudoBinary(0), PseudoBinary(1)],
           [PseudoBinary(1), PseudoBinary(0), PseudoBinary(0)],
           [PseudoBinary(1), PseudoBinary(0), PseudoBinary(1)]])

 baseRes = numpy.dot(base,base)
 pseudoRes = numpy.dot(pseudo,pseudo)

 print("baseRes\n",baseRes)
 print("pseudoRes\n",pseudoRes)
```

Prints :

```
baseRes
 [[2 0 2]
 [1 0 1]
 [2 0 2]]
pseudoRes
 [[P3 P2 P2]
 [P3 P1 P2]
 [P3 P2 P2]]
```

Comment: Pretty much *anything* you do with an object array will be slow. None of the reasons NumPy is usually fast apply to object arrays.

Comment: " bunch of pointer dereferences may occur instead of directly reading from contiguous memory" That is **sure** to occur. Essentially, a `numpy.ndarray` of `dtype=object` is a bad Python `list`. Numpy was not really designed to be used with custom objects, but rather, with **num**bers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much *anything* you do with object arrays is going to be slow. None of the reasons NumPy is usually fast apply to object arrays.

- Object arrays cannot store their elements contiguously. They must store and dereference pointers.

  - They don't know how much space they would have to allocate for their elements.
  - Their elements may not all be the same size.
  - The elements you insert into an object array have already been allocated outside the array, and they cannot be copied.
- Object arrays must perform dynamic dispatch on all element operations. Every time they add or multiply two elements, they have to figure out *how* to do that all over again.
- Object arrays have no way to accelerate the implementation of their elements, such as your slow, interpreted `__add__` and `__mul__`.
- Object arrays cannot avoid the memory allocation associated with their element operations, such as the allocation of a new `PseudoBinary` object and a new `__dict__` for that object on every element `__add__` or `__mul__`.
- Object arrays cannot parallelize operations, as all operations on their elements will require the GIL to be held.
- Object arrays cannot use LAPACK or BLAS, as there are no LAPACK or BLAS functions for arbitrary Python datatypes.
- Etc.

Basically, every reason doing Python math without NumPy is slow also applies to doing anything with object arrays.

---

As for how to improve your performance? Don't use object arrays. Use regular arrays, and either find a way to implement the thing you want in terms of the operations NumPy provides, or write out the loops explicitly and use something like Numba or Cython to compile your code.

Answer (score 1):

The `dot`  is  an outer product followed by sum on one axis.

For your `pseudo`, the `dot` is marginally faster than the sum of product equivalents:

```
In [18]: timeit (pseudo[:,:,None]*pseudo[None,:,:]).sum(axis=1)
75.7 µs ± 3.14 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [19]: timeit  np.dot(pseudo, pseudo)
63.9 µs ± 1.91 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

For `base`, `dot` is substantially faster than the equivalent.

```
In [20]: timeit (base[:,:,None]*base[None,:,:]).sum(axis=1)
13.9 µs ± 24.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [21]: timeit  np.dot(base,base)
1.58 µs ± 53.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

So with a numeric array, `dot` can pass the whole task to optimized compiled code (BLAS or other).

We could get a further idea of how object dtype affects the speed by creating a numeric object array, and comparing the simple element product:

```
In [28]: baso = base.astype(object)
In [29]: timeit base*base
766 ns ± 48.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [30]: timeit baso*baso
2.45 µs ± 73.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [31]: timeit pseudo*pseudo
13.7 µs ± 41.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

---

Using 'or' (`|`) instead of `*`, we can calculate the same thing as `pseudo` but with `base`:

```
In [34]: (base[:,:,None] | base[None,:,:]).sum(axis=1)
Out[34]: 
array([[3, 2, 2],
       [3, 1, 2],
       [3, 2, 2]], dtype=int32)
In [35]: timeit (base[:,:,None] | base[None,:,:]).sum(axis=1)
15.1 µs ± 492 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```